# Airflow admin UI shows example dags

Tags: python-2.7, webserver, airflow

I am trying to setup Airflow on my system locally. I have used:

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/Documents/Project/airflow
```

Then I have initialized airflow db by

```
airflow initdb
```

Then I started airflow web server using :

```
airflow webserver -p 8080
```

Now when I open localhost:8080, the admin panel shows example dags from 
**/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/example-dags**
and not from **~/Documents/Project/airflow/dags** folder.

Whereas `airflow list_dags` on command line shows dags from my project folder.

Could not figure out the reason. Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apart from export path mentioned, airflow by default also creates a folder in your home directory when you run `airflow initdb`. Hence it will use config file from home directory, so in order to load your DAGs, delete airflow folder from home directory.

Answer (score 10):

For those who are still looking for an answer, Airflow configuration file, `aiflow.cfg` has one line

```
load_example = True
```

It's good to get started, but you probably want to set this to FALSE and restart airflow by using `airflow resetdb`.